# Aptana Studio 3 Doesn't Run in Debian Squeeze KDE

Tags: debian, aptana3, kde-plasma

I have just installed Aptana Studio 3 on a fresh 64 bit Debian Squeeze KDE system. When I try to run it, I get a bouncing aptana icon and then nothing happens. The splash screen never appears.

Web search found that a Spanish-speaking user had the same problem but never received an answer.  http://foro.ubuntu-guia.com/Instalacion-Aptana-Studio-3-En-Debian-Testing-KDE-64-Bits-td4025304.html

Aptana Studio is a version of the Eclipse IDE that has python development support built into it. I tried installing eclipse and openjdk to see if I was missing pre-requisites.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y eclipse
```

However it doesn't help.

Does anyone have thoughts on resolving this issue?

Comment: It looks like the Sun JDK is required to run Aptana 3. OpenJDK is not supported.

Comment: I downloaded the Sun JDK from this URL:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

I applied installation instructions from here (but with the latest JDK version): http://linux-knowledgebase.com/en/Linux/HOWTO/sun%20java%20debian%20squeeze

Unfortunately still no luck.

Comment: When I download Eclipse from the eclipse.org site, it works fine on my system. This must be something specific to Aptana. Both Aptana Studio 2 and 3 fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to replace

```
Exec=/opt/aptana/AptanaStudio3
```

for

```
Exec=/opt/aptana/aptana
```